# Intermittent registration

Tags: civievent

I have an event registration setup. I have a person that has tried to register from his home internet provider and mobile phone provider and it will not register him. He has tried 3 different email address. One email address worked once, I deleted it from the backend and it would not work again. If I use any of his email address to register him it works. I've also had 5 others register and it was fine. I had this same issue last year with an event. Some people were able to register and some were not. Any suggestions where I can look for the issue?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what happens when it does not work?  Does the user get an error message?  Does the civicrm log file record anything? A screenshot of what happens when the user tries to register might help us.

Comment: There is no error and there is also not a page that says Thank you for registering, an email has been sent to.... I have the log file for the website if that would be helpful.

Comment: So the same person drives a hundred miles away for a visit and has no trouble registering from his cell and a desktop computer. No rhyme or reason.

Comment: I see this in the debug: Jan 27 00:37:46  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home4/gcohorg/public_html/gcoh2/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home4/gcohorg/public_html/gcoh2/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(120): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")

Comment: The same person went back home and tried two different email address and could not register. His wife tried from her cell phone with her email address on the same wifi and it worked fine. Anybody intrigued yet?